Commands not recognized when right side of pipe
Environment
OS: macOS Sonoma 14.5
Shell: ZSH 5.9
Keyboard: Danish
Problem
When piping two commands (using |) the command on the right side is not recognized. Eventhough it is a builtin command like echo. The weird thing is, that this is only an issue sometimes. When I delete the pipe and write it again a couple of times, eventually it works. I write the pipe on my keyboard with OPTION + i.
Example
heroku config | grep REDIS_URL
zsh: command not found:  grep
heroku config | grep REDIS_URL
REDIS_URL:

The second command worked, but the first didn't. The lines are copied directly from my shell.
Question
Any suggestions on what is going wrong?
And how I can fix this?
Both ChatGPT and Perplexity was to no help.

What do you mean: "I write the pipe on my keyboard with OPTION + i."? Option+i does not produce a correct pipe.

It is a danish keyboard

That might be worth mentioning in your post! You can [edit] it with the additional information.

It feels like you're adding a No-Break-Space (U+00A0 0xC2A0) after the pipe, so you end up trying to execute the $'\xC2\xA0'grep' command

@SiKing it was mentioned! However I could see that the formatting was off, so the keyboard and the shell were on the same line. I added a linebreak now.

@Fravadona Do you know how I can avoid that?

IDK how to fix the problem but you could avoid typing a space after the pipe, for eg.  heroku config |grep REDIS_URL

There must be a difference in the two commands, maybe some invisible character around grep. If you type the commands instead of copying, it always works, right? If this is so, I would debug it like this: Create a new file with an editor, which operates inside the terminal (for instance, nano test.txt. Then paste your non-working command into the editor and save the file. Then look at the file with i.e. od -cx test.txt.

@user1934428
How do I read the output?
It seems different though with two asterics after the pipe on the command that does no work and non on the one that does work.
I think Fravadona is on to something, I maybe accidentally write Option + Space instead of just space. Could that be it?

Well, you see the hex representation of your file. If you see differences in the two versions, you can see which bytes differe, and what bit pattern is in the differing bytes. Since you didn't post, how the two cases look like, I can't help here.

0000000    h   e   r   o   k   u       c   o   n   f   i   g       |    
6568    6f72    756b    6320    6e6f    6966    2067    c27c
0000020   **   g   r   e   p       R   E   D   I   S   _   U   R   L  \n
67a0    6572    2070    4552    4944    5f53    5255    0a4c
0000040
This is the command that is not working.

TL;DR You aren't releasing the option key soon enough, after you type | but before you hit the space bar.

On macOS, ⌥Space produces U+00A0, a non-breaking space that is not considered whitespace by the shell. When you type that character, you attempt to execute the command  grep, not grep, which you can seen in your error message (^ added for emphasis):
zsh: command not found:  grep
                       ^^

which is different from
zsh: command not found: grep 
                       ^

You are typing ⌥i to type the | character. Sometimes, you release the option key soon enough that you type a literal space character; other times, you are holding it too long and get the non-breaking space. That's why the error seems "random".
